# SAGA processing and special characters

Tags: qgis, saga, encoding

I’m using some SAGA processing for vector layers in QGIS.
Is it a way to change the default encoding in SAGA?

I have attribut value with french characters (é, ê, à) and after a SAGA Union, they are all changed into '_'.

[EDIT]: I use QGIS 3.28 and no, I don’t use the next gen, but the provider that comes with the installer.

My layer are created within QGIS with UTF-8, within a geopackage.

The problem is my 2 layers are very similar, and if I use the default « union » tool, QGIS says it can’t add a multiline into a multipolyon layer. But SAGA does it without a problem, except that all the special French characters (é, à, è, ê, etc.) are changed to '_'.

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What QGIS version? As you probably use the *SAGA Next Gen* QGIS plugin: What version? Have your layers containing the attributes been created inside QGIS or have they been loaded from an external source? If the latter: What character set do the files use?

Comment: A workaround would be to join the newly created layers by SAGA with the initial layer to copy the original attribute values from there.

Comment: See my updates!